# A row in MySQL doesn't change, even after I update it in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        results = None
        results = Decay.objects.filter(next_decay_at__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
        for r in results:
            print r.next_decay_at

        time.sleep(10)
```

For some reason, even if I update "next_decay_at" in the table, this Decay.objects.filter query seems to be cached and when I print "next_decay_at", it didn't seem to change! It prints the same everytime.

When I restart the script, it seems to have changed and the print statement changed.  But then when I let it run again, it prints the same over and over. Could it be that the while loop is caching the result set?

Comment: I query it in Mysql (SELECT next_decay_val FROM...)  and it changed!!! But not during this script. It keeps printing the same over and over, until I Restart the script.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Django's [transaction handling](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: ok. read it. I don't do transaction_manually commit or anything. It's just a basic ".save()" .  Another script does that every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

QuerySet caches the results. To quote the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets):

> In a newly created QuerySet, the cache is empty. The first time a QuerySet is evaluated -- and, hence, a database query happens -- Django saves the query results in the QuerySet's cache and returns the results that have been explicitly requested (e.g., the next element, if the QuerySet is being iterated over). Subsequent evaluations of the QuerySet reuse the cached results.

Change your code to the following:

```
date_from = datetime.datetime.now()
for r in Decay.objects.filter(next_decay_at__lte=date_from):
    print r.next_decay_at
```

Or use [iterator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.iterator) method:

```
results = Decay.objects.filter(next_decay_at__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
for r in results.iterator():
    print r.next_decay_at
```

Comment: For the benefit of future searchers: this is not the correct answer. There is nothing in the code posted by the OP that would cause caching, and moving the evaluation of `datetime.now()` to a separate variable would not change anything.

Comment: I disagree. In OP's code records are cached in the internal QuerySet cache, not by django.core.cache. Please, read the docs i've linked to.

Comment: And I've moved out datatime to preserve code functionality e.g. initialize date only once.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing has nothing to do with QuerySet. It has to do with transaction management. When your request or script starts, Django opens a transaction, and until that transaction commits or rolls back, it isn't getting anything that intermittently happens in other transactions.

If you commit your transaction and run that code block again, you should get updated results.

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.commit()
```